# Minesweeper 2d Matrix (how to find path with generator) - how to trick range()

Tags: python, matrix, minesweeper

How does one trick the range() function to go in reverse if parameter 1 bigger than parameter 2. It's a coding project / problem i have atm. Any ideas.

The function `safe_passage(x0, y0, x1, y1, mine):`
gets 5 parameters

```
(x0, y0) is 1 coordinate
(x1, y1) is 2 coordinate
mine is a dict that has the coordinates of mines = {(3, 0), (1, 1), (6, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (6, 3)}
```

I've devised a function that allows you to find a path from point a to point b and between these 2 points must not be a "mine" in between them for the function to return TRUE. Ff there is a mine in between them the function returns FALSE

a example of the 2d table and the movement:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ^ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ^ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ^ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ^ | < | < | B |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This is the generator that returns true or false if there is a bomb in the path of the 2 coordinates.

```
def safe_passage(x0, y0, x1, y1, mine):
   return(all([(x,y) not in [(x,y) for (x,y) in [(x2, y2) for x2 in range(x0,x1+1) for y2 in range(y0, y1+1)]] for (x,y) in mine]))
```

It works fine but the problem starts when you insert a x1 that is bigger than x0 or y1 that is bigger than y0.
Than the in range() doesn't function because x0 parameter is higher than x1 or y.
The catch to all of this is that it has to be written in 1 line. I would use a if() to test if x1>x0 and add a step to the range(x0,x1+1, -1) but it's not allowed to use more than 1 line to devise this function. Any ideas ?

[SOLVED:]

```
def safe_passage(x0, y0, x1, y1, mine):
 return(all([(x,y) not in [(x,y) for (x,y) in [(x2, y2) for x2 in range(min(x0,x1),max(x0,x1)+1) for y2 in range(min(y0,y1),max(y0,y1)+1)]] for (x,y) in mine]))
```

Comment: What about `range(min(x0,x1),max(x0,x1)+1)`? As far as I can see, the order does not matter.

Comment: @Hennich cheers i've totaly forgot about the min max methods. Thanks for the help!